# Retrieve records when value in column changes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

**I am using SQL Server 2012.**
I have this table below. I would like to get records when the **Name** changes (see column result). I' m not getting with this code.

```
SELECT [Date], [Name]
FROM myTable as T1
WHERE T1.[Date] <> 
( SELECT T2.[Date]
FROM myTable as T2
WHERE T1.[Name] = T2.[Name])
```

[image]

**Expexted result**

[image]

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: What makes the 2/4 John row come first? Do you have another column to help sort or does the date column actually have time data first?

Comment: The table is sorted by Date. I want to retrieve the records (Date and Name) each time the name changes.

Comment: But a table isn't "sorted" - and three rows *have the same date*. (Actually there are two for 6/4 too.) I could sort those rows in any order and would you know? Is the name change more important than the date change?

Comment: The date is formatted "dd/mm/yyyy", so for me the table is sorted by date. The Name is important, because I need the records when the name changes.

Comment: The part that doesn't make sense is you "need the records when the name changes". Except that would imply you want `02/04/2019    John`... because that's when the name "changed". I think what you *really* want is the *earliest date for each name in the table*. Because that's what your results seem to show.

Comment: You have John on the 01/04/2019, so it is retrieved because is the first on the table. You have John on the 02/04/2019, so it is not retrieved because the name didn't change regarding the previous record. Do you understand now?

Comment: It is not clear how you define which is the “previous record“. You say by date but what happens when 2 or 3 rows have the same date? How do we define previous and next row in this case? Voting to close until you clarify. Aaron asked the same question 5 hours ago.

Answer (score 2):

```
;
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT [DATE], [NAME],
    LAG([NAME]) OVER (ORDER BY [DATE]) AS [PREVIOUS]
    FROM myTable
)

SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE [NAME] <> [PREVIOUS]
ORDER BY [DATE]
;
```

Comment: Your `TOP 1` needs `ORDER BY [DATE]` as well, otherwise it may return any row. Or you could remove that and simply use `WHERE [NAME] <> [PREVIOUS] OR [PREVIOUS] IS NULL`